# No se puede borrar el último presupuesto de cada departamento

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, trigger

Tengo una base de datos empleado-departamento-presupuesto donde cada departamento tiene al menos un presupuesto y para esto he preparado estos triggers pero no me concuerda, ya que tiene que ser el último presupuesto de cada departamento.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ULTIMOPRESUPUESTO
BEFORE DELETE ON PRESUPUESTO
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  V_CANTIDAD NUMBER(4);
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(ANNO) INTO V_CANTIDAD FROM PRESUPUESTO;
  IF V_CANTIDAD=1 THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20234, 'No puedes borrar el ultimo presupuesto');
  END IF;
END;
```

¿O sería poniendo en la consulta agrupados por departamento?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ULTIMOPRESUPUESTO
BEFORE DELETE ON PRESUPUESTO
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  V_CANTIDAD NUMBER(4);
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(ANNO) INTO V_CANTIDAD FROM PRESUPUESTO GROUP BY DEPT_NO;
  IF V_CANTIDAD=1 THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20234, 'No puedes borrar el ultimo presupuesto');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Podrías colocar la estructura de esas tablas para comprender mejor el esquema.

Answer (score 0):

Estas eliminando desde una pantalla de tu aplicacion o desde un procedimiento?
Si es desde pantalla controla desde ahi que puedas eliminar el ultimo presupuesto.
Si utilizas procedimiento pues calcula cuantos registros existen y solo para n-1 ordenandolos del mas antiguo al mas nuevo.